# error is "selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable"

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I want to upload an excel file on "https://www.onlinedoctranslator.com/translationform" but I'm getting the following error

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable"

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\Nitin_Data\chrom_driver\chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.onlinedoctranslator.com/translationform')
filepath = 'excel file path here'
upload_file = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='dz-message 
needsclick']")
upload_file.send_keys(filepath)
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the code where you access the element into a loop, so you can try to access it several times and wait a short time between each attempt?

Comment: thank's for comment .I hv not tried this.

Comment: I dont see such xpath "//div[@class='dz-message needsclick']" in the DOM, There is no wonder to get the exception. Also please share the steps in question, so it will help us to answer your question,

Comment: help me to find node or selector :upload_file = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='dz-message 
needsclick']")

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack, but I've used it in the past with success. You could try locating the file `input` element on the page and running some Javascript to make it visible, then sends your file path text there.

```
file_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display = 'block';", file_input)
file_input.send_keys(filepath)
```

If `display: block` does not work, you could try toggling the visiblity:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.visibility= 'visible';", file_input)
```

Comment: thanks .it's work ... but after uploading file I'm not able to click on translate button,please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='translation-button']").click()`. Make sure you have two different languages selected in the dropdowns too -- the button will not be active until you have a valid language selection chosen.

Comment: @nitingharge did this solution help fix your problem?

Comment: @nitingharge then feel free to mark this as answer to your question so other users can see that it was helpful for your problem :)

Comment: Christine after more than 2 time run ...it was failed to click on transfer...I dont know what happen please help.